# Print out all files in a folder and its subfolders on a Mac

Tags: macos, unix

I have a project with a lot of files under /app. There are also subfolders with files. How can I print(hard copy) these files all out without manually printing each one?

Note: Not the file names. I want to print(hard copy) the contents of all files under /app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find /app
```

If you want print only directories, specify it with `-type d` (`-type f` to print files only):

```
find /app -type d
```

**UPDATE**

```
find /app -type f -print -exec cat {} \;
```

To get file hard copied, use `lpr` command:

```
find /app -type f -print -exec lpr {} \;
```

Comment: Looking to print out the contents of each of those files. Question edited.

Comment: Trying it out in 5 minutes!

Comment: it prints the contents of the files to the screen but nothing to the printer...?

Comment: @slindsey3000, Replace `cat` with `lpr`: `find /app -type f -print -exec lpr {} \;`

Comment: Yes! Worked. find app -print -exec lpr {} \;